# build fauiler on ant fresh install

Tags: java, ant, ubuntu-14.04, dspace

good day
PLEASE HELP, i am install dspace 6.2 on ubuntu 14.04 lts and i compiled maven package successfuly but when im running this code

```
sudo ant fresh install
```

i get this error below

```
dspace@dspace:~$ locate build.xml
/home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config/build.xml
/usr/share/man/man5/build.xml.5.gz
dspace@dspace:~$ cd /home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config/
dspace@dspace:~/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config$ ls
build.xml
dspace@dspace:~/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config$ sudo ant fresh_install
Buildfile: /home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config/build.xml:111: /home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/src/main/config/lib does not exist.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

has maven finished without errors?

Build.xml should be at /home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/

Comment: i cant seem to find that directory " /home/dspace/downloads/dspace-6.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-installer/"